# EditText field in Android to corectly format

Tags: android

As the title asks, I want to correctly monitor an Edit Text field to format the entered numbers as a currency with a "." being l=placed or inserted after the last 3 digits of the cell.

In all as the user inputs the numbers and the field expands the EditText will reflect that the numbers that they entered will reflect as a currency, example below:

user enters "123456789"

the EditText will reflect this as : "123.456.789"

Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

Comment: use `addTextChangedListener()` for `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditText variableName = ....
variableName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {                
            if(3 == s.length() % 4){
                s.append('.'); // this change will fire this event again, be careful, avoid infinite loops
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
public void CLICKED(View v){
     EditText txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editnumber);
     String string = txt.getText().toString();
     TextView destination = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bar);

     String s = string;
    if(string.length()>2){
        s="";
        int dots = string.length()/3;
        int charsLeft = string.length()-dots*3;
        if(string.length()-dots*3 >0){
            s+=string.substring(0,  charsLeft);
            s+='.';
        }
        String subs[] = new String[dots];
        for(int i = 0; i < dots; i++){
            subs[i] = string.substring(charsLeft+i*3, charsLeft+3+i*3);
            if(i!=dots-1)
                subs[i]+=".";
        }
        for(int i=0;i<dots;i++){
            s+=subs[i];
        }

    }
    destination.setText(s);
}
```